# Getting sudo to work for an alias

Tags: bash, sudo, path, alias

I installed Sublime Text 3 in Fedora 20 which has got GNOME, as I couldn't get it being *called* from terminal I created a `.bash_aliases` file which a line like this:

```
alias sublime='sublime_text'
```

And so also added the sublime_text file location to the PATH by editing `.bashrc` file adding:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/share/applications/sublime-text-3/
```

However, when I want to edit any file for which I might get ***sudo privilege*** first I want to do:

```
sudo sublime sudoLikelyFile
```

or

```
sudo sublime_text sudoLikelyFile
```

However I'm getting:

```
sudo: sublime: command not found
```

How can I work around for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two potential problems here.

Firstly, you need to make your shell expand aliases after `sudo`:

```
alias sudo='sudo '
```

From `man bash`:

> If the last character of the alias value is a blank, then the next command word following the alias is also checked for alias expansion.

Secondly, on many distributions, `$PATH` is not propagated to the new shell by sudo. You can manually change `secure_path` to add the directory which the `sublime_text` executable is in:

```
Defaults secure_path = [...]:/usr/local/share/applications/sublime-text-3
```

...or you can disable secure_path altogether (note: `secure_path` makes sure that an attacker cannot change your path and use it to influence the command you will run as root, so consider this carefully):

```
Defaults !secure_path
```

Comment: How can I change `secure_path`?

Comment: @diegoaguilar By using the `Defaults` listed above. If it doesn't exist, you may not have the issue.