# How do I make 'sudo ll' work?

Tags: files, ls

Every once in awhile, I find myself needing to list files in a directory that I don't have execution permission on. So I do a sudo:

```
>sudo ll /opt/mydir
[sudo] password for civfan:
sudo: ll: command not found
```

And then I say, "D'oh!" and switch to `ls`. And then remember I really wanted `ls -l`. And then remember I REALLY wanted `ls -al`.

Can someone save me from myself?

I see that `ll` is an alias for my user:

```
>alias ll
alias ll='ls -alF'
```

How do I make `sudo ll` work? Presumably I need an alias for root... if so, how do I set aliases for root?

EDIT: My guess is trying to run `sudo ll` is so common that this question deserves to stand alone from the suggested duplicate.

UPDATE: root already has an `ll` alias!

```
civfan@civfan:~>sudo -s
root@civfan:~>alias ll
alias ll='ls -alF'
```

And yet `sudo ll` doesn't work...

**UPDATE 2 - answer:**

The answer in the [suggested duplicate question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/109726/84008) fits my workflow the best, and I don't see any downsides. I wanted to note it here:

```
alias sudo="sudo "
```

From man bash:

> If the last character of the alias value is a blank, then the next
> command word following the alias is also checked for alias expansion.

Comment: Can't you just add 'sudo ls -alF' to the alias? or you can log as a root and then edit your file where the aliases are ~/.bashrc and add the alias

Comment: @SaulOrtega I don't always want to run `ll` as sudo. To your second point, can you elaborate in an answer?

Comment: In my second answer I meant log as root with (su) then open your alias file depending on your system and add the same alias you have there I mean alias ll. then when you want to execute that command it will prompt you for a password.

Comment: @SaulOrtega After switching to root using either `su` or `sudo -s`, it turns out the `ll` alias already exists. I don't know why `sudo ll` doesn't work, then.

Comment: does it work when you are logged in as a root?

Comment: @SaulOrtega `ll` works when switched to root user.

Comment: sudo -c "source /root/.bashrc && ll"

Comment: `ll` is a shell alias, `sudo` does not run the command in a shell.

Comment: @richard Ahhh ok. That makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

-**Edit for adult users**-  This alias description feels a bit like magic and looks cool, when you want to impress your friends, but they aren't! Remember that you are using your shell interactively, because it looks so cool and you have so many great commands to combine, but when you grow up, or your software does, you possibly want to automate a few things.

When you automate things with sudo, it is best to not rely on, tricks to help bash users in interactive sessions.

Of course you can simply add such features to the sudo command on your own:

```
mv /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/sudo_orig
ed /usr/bin/sudo
a
#!/bin/sh
cmd="$*"
if [ $1.cmd = "ll.cmd" ]
then
  shift
  cmd="ls -alF $*"
elif [ $1.cmd = ...more definitions... ]
then ...
fi
sudo_orig $cmd
.
w
q
chmod 755 /usr/bin/sudo
```

This is how you can create a toolset that matches your needs, if you really think you need it this way ;)
-**END-OF-EDIT**-

A shell alias is used as an interactive part of the shell. When you call sudo you leave the shell and execute a command.

You could either enter an interactive shell with `sudo -s`, define your aliases and use them, or you have to rewrite your aliases as commands or functions, for example use a folder /root/alias-cmds and write the command `/root/alias-cmds/ll`:

```
echo "ls -alF" > /root/alias-cmds/ll; chmod 700 /root/alias-cmds/ll;
```

now you can use

```
sudo 'PATH=$PATH:/root/alias-cmds ll'
```

Another option is to define

```
alias sudoll='sudo ls -alF'
```

and use `sudoll` instead of `sudo ll`.

Comment: I really want `sudo ll` to work, since that fits the typical workflow of `sudo x` when just `x` doesn't have permission. I'd also prefer it to work with something simpler than adding a new command to root's path.

Comment: BTW: The use of additional commands is quite more stable and more flexible in different situations. I guess it is quite simple to generate these commands from your aliases, so you don't even need to write them by hand!